# node-key-sender can't access jar file

Tags: java, node.js

I'm developing a small tool to send a keyboard key to the server. 
When I use the jar file, without NodeJS it works great

[image: Java jar]

But when I execute te same code (it should work, out of the box) I got a error message

`(node:3092) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Command failed: java -jar 'D:\RELS\node_modules\node-key-sender\jar\key-sender.jar' q
Error: Unable to access jarfile 'D:\RELS\node_modules\node-key-sender\jar\key-sender.jar'`

The jar file already has Everyone Full Control permission.

(relevant code)

```
app.get('/key_q', function (req, res) {
  try {
    ks.sendKeys(['q']);
  } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
  }

  //console.log(e);
})
```

How can I help NodeJS to access the jar file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I needed to put the location between double quotes.